# What's Going Wrong Here (Erasing My Home Partition)

Tags: partitioning, dd

I'm using the DD command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda4 bs=10M
```

from a Xubuntu live USB. SDA4 is my Home partition, which has been wiped normally before attempting to use this command.

This is the error I'm getting back in the terminal:

```
dd: error writing '/dev/sda4': No space left on device
28474+0 records in
28473+0 records out
298563141632 bytes (299 GB, 278 GiB) copied, 4957.43 s, 60.2 MB/s
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is the partition size an exact integral multiple of your chosen 10M block size?

Comment: I think you are missing the block count. You have block size (`bs=10M`) but are missing `count=N` where N=number of blocks. I can't confirm because I don't zero out data partitions only first 512 bytes of disk to clear MBR (Master Boot Record).

Comment: Okay, I think I follow, so what should I add to correct this? The partition is 278.02 GiB in size. I was following a guide on the internet, so the bs=10M is not specifically chosen by me, I can remove it if I need to!

Comment: I think the key thing is to tell it how many bytes to zero out... Block Size x Block Count = number of bytes to zero out.

Comment: I appreciate that but I don't know how to translate that to the command :(

Comment: What does `df -h` report for /dev/sda4?

Comment: I tried just "df -h" and then "df -h /dev/sda4" and the second returns: "udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev". Sorry for my noobiness btw, but I don't think I'm doing this right

Comment: How has sda4 "been wiped normally before attempting to use this command"? Why bother zero writing it again?

Comment: @Xen2050 Your point is valid. The question was how to avoid the error in the first place. KUP your data partition has already be scrubbed clean with zeroes written to every byte and you don't have to pursue this again. Do you wish to continue?

Comment: I was also just wondering what the "normal" wipe was... something like  Disks (gnome-disk-utility) Format & overwrite with zeros? Or `wipefs` (that doesn't actually overwrite data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd` keeps writing until it fills the entire device, the error "No space left on device" means it's full. It wrote 298563141632 bytes (299 GB, 278 GiB) and you said your sda4 is 278 GiB, so you've already filled it with zeros, it worked and nothing went wrong.

Evidently `dd` doesn't care that much about writing full blocks, it writes out as much as it can and will report writing one less block than it read.

Just to double-check I tried this small experiment with a 1M loop device:

```
fallocate -l 1M file1
sudo losetup /dev/loop1 file1
sudo hd /dev/loop1
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00100000
```

my fallocate already zero fills, so ready for writing dd in 2M and 700,000 blocks to a 1,048,576 device

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=2M |tr '\0' x | sudo dd of=/dev/loop1 bs=2M
dd: error writing '/dev/loop1': No space left on device
0+121 records in
0+120 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0274112 s, 38.3 MB/s
```

No space left error, but still wrote x's to every byte of /dev/loop1

```
$ sudo hd /dev/loop1
00000000  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
*
00100000
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/loop1 bs=700000 
dd: error writing '/dev/loop1': No space left on device
2+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0148556 s, 70.6 MB/s
```

Again with a slightly smaller bs, still filled the device

```
$ sudo hd /dev/loop1
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00100000
```

Even matching the bs to the device size (in this example 1M) still gives the error

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M  of=/dev/loop1
dd: error writing '/dev/loop1': No space left on device
2+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0164516 s, 63.7 MB/s
```

Unless you match the size with `bs` & `count` (after filling with x's again)

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/loop1 bs=1M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0213422 s, 49.1 MB/s
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that it had finished, I was too focused on the error, thank you for the time, support and effort, it's appreciated!

Comment: Welcome :) I even did a few quick tests just to make sure, I read somewhere that not all `dd`'s are created equal. You could always read the device to be absolutely sure it's all zero's, a graphical hex editor that works with big files is nice (bless?), or dd + some math, or read the whole thing with `hd`, etc